# Django QuerySet for Counting items for each distinct field in any given month, including 0 value

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
#models.py
class Orders(models.Model):
    orderid = models.IntegerField(db_column='orderID', primary_key=True) 
    pickupdate = models.DateField(db_column='pickupDate', blank=True, null=True)  
    pickupstore = models.ForeignKey(Branch, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='pickupStore', blank=True, null=True,related_name = 'pickupstore')  

class Branch(models.Model):
    branchid = models.IntegerField(db_column='branchID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

The pickupstore field in Orders Class model refers to Branch Class Model.

I would like to count the number of pickups for all stores(branches) in any given month, including when stores(branches) have 0 pickups in that particular month

This is my solution for counting the number or pickup in all stores (branches in January of 2006, however, it doesn't include stores that have 0 orders

```
branchs = Orders.objects.all().select_related('pickupstore').values('pickupstore__city').filter(pickupdate__year = 2006, pickupdate__month = 1).annotate(num=Count('pickupstore__city')).order_by('pickupstore__city')
branchs = branchs.values('pickupstore__city').filter(pickupdate__year = year, pickupdate__month = month)
branchs = branchs.annotate(num=Count('pickupstore__city')).order_by('pickupstore__city')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate() first then filter on it:

```
pickup_branch = Orders.objects.all().select_related('pickupstore').annotate(num=Count('pickupstore__city')).values('pickupstore__city').filter(pickupdate__year = 2006, pickupdate__month = 1).order_by('pickupstore__city')
```

if it doesn't work try this:

```
all_branch = Orders.objects.all().select_related('pickupstore')
pickup_branch = Orders.objects.all().select_related('pickupstore').values('pickupstore__city').filter(pickupdate__year = 2006, pickupdate__month = 1).annotate(num=Count('pickupstore__city')).order_by('pickupstore__city')    
zero_pickup_branch = [branch for branch in all_branch if not branch in pickup_branch]
```

this will give you branches with 0 pickups
then you can simply put values 0 for those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base your filter on Branch as you want all branches even the ones that don't have any orders for your filters, so you need a left outer join. There are a few ways to do this, but for your case, the following will work.

```
branches_with_orders= Branch.objects.filter(pickupstore__pickupdate__year=2006, pickupstore__pickupdate__month=1).annotate(num=Count('city'))

branches_without_orders = Branch.objects.exclude(pk__in=branches_with_orders).extra(select={'num': 0}).values('city','num')

all_branches = list(branches_without_orders) + list(branches_with_orders.values('city','num'))

print all_branches

>>> [{'city': u'A', 'num': 0}, {'city': u'B', 'num': 0}, {'city': u'C','num': 4}]
```